# How can I disable the automatic transliteration of Arabic?

Tags: arabic, translate

How can I disable the automatic transliteration of Arabic?
I want to write my French report including some Arabic sentences. So I am using the `arabtex` package but when writing an Arabic sentence like this

```
\begin{arabtext}
السَلامُ عَليكم ورَحمةُ الله وبَركاته  
\end{arabtext}
```

I got this:

```
السَلامُ عَليكم ورَحمةُ الله وبَركاته 
ālsalāmu alykm wrah.mtu āllh wbarkāth
```

I don't want this transliteration. How can I disable it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command you want is `\transfalse`.  For example,

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{arabtex}
\begin{document}
\setarab
\novocalize
\spreadtrue
\transfalse
\begin{RLtext}
klAm fI m.h.d al-_hyr
\end{RLtext}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 2):

If you're not limited to `(la)tex`, why don't you use `arabxetex` package?

I think using it with `xelatex` have more options than `arabtex`, e.g. you can change the main font for Arabic typesetting (default is Amiri font).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{arabxetex}
\begin{document}

\begin{arab}[voc]
السَلامُ عَليكم ورَحمةُ الله وبَركاته  
\end{arab}

\end{document}
```

[image]