Auto transliteration
Given Arabic text, is there a LaTeX package that gives its Romanized version? See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanization_of_Arabic
This is basically the reverse of what ArabTeX does.
E.g: خَبَر --> Khabar
and if a paragraph is given, then it should show the Romanized text in-between
the paragraph text. So every line of the paragraph has a corresponding Romanized
version of it right below it.

The problem (question) mentioned here seems to do what you want: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/462601/how-can-i-disable-the-automatic-transliteration-of-arabic?rq=1

You might be able to use a token cycle in the manner of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/597535/how-to-generate-transliteration-of-bengali-word/597563#597563

This is not a complete answer, but rather an extensible scheme. It uses LuaLaTeX (preferably the latest) with the light-weight and rabbit-powered pgfparser. You will have to add the rules for all the characters you want. It can't be guaranteed that the conversion rules can cover all of the transliteration exactly using this scheme. It may require some advanced programming if there is no one-to-one mapping in the original and the transliterated Arabic writing. I had tried something like this for Devanagari and realized that it is much more complicated than I thought it would be. Best of luck for Arabic ;-)
I will explain the scheme to you. You need to focus on the following line from the code:
\pgfparserdef{arabtrans}{initial}{the letter ب}%
{b}%

Just replace the Arabic character with another one and use the required Latin character in the argument. This just replaces the particular character with the code seen in the argument. You may have any arbitrary TeX code there. This is a sample:
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage[bidi=basic]{babel}
\babelprovide[import,onchar={ids fonts}]{arabic}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[%
  Renderer          = {Harfbuzz},%
  Script            = {Arabic}%
]{Amiri-Regular.ttf}
\usepackage{pgfparser}
\pgfparserdef{arabtrans}{initial}{the letter خ}%
{x}%
\pgfparserdef{arabtrans}{initial}{the letter ب}%
{b}%
\pgfparserdef{arabtrans}{initial}{the letter ر}%
{r}%
\pgfparserdef{arabtrans}{initial}{the letter َ}%
{a}%
\pgfparserdef{arabtrans}{initial}{blank space}%
{ }%
\pgfparserdef{arabtrans}{initial}{the character ;}%
{\pgfparserswitch{final}}

\NewDocumentCommand \transliterate { m }{%
  #1 (\pgfparserparse{arabtrans}#1;)%
}

\begin{document}
\transliterate{خَبَر}
\end{document}



If you find this helpful and are planning on using it, consider pinging the author and make him change the example given in the documentation ;-)
